# Filtering with symfony2

Tags: php, url-routing, symfony

Is there any open source (or example) code for Symfony2 which can filter certain model using multiple parameters? A good example of what I'm looking for can be seen on this Trulia web page.

`http://www.trulia.com/for_sale/30000-1000000_price/10001_zip/`

`http://www.trulia.com/for_rent/Chicago,IL/#for_rent/Chicago,IL/0-500_price/wd,dw_amenities/sm_dogs_pets"`

`http://www.trulia.com/for_rent/Chicago,IL/#for_rent/Chicago,IL/400-500_price/wd,dw_amenities`

`http://www.trulia.com/for_rent/Chicago,IL/#for_rent/Chicago,IL/wd,dw_amenities"`

`http://www.trulia.com/for_rent/Chicago,IL/#for_rent/Chicago,IL/400p_price/dw,cs_amenities`

`http://www.trulia.com/for_rent/Chicago,IL/#for_rent/Chicago,IL/1p_beds/1p_baths/400p_price/dw,cs_amenities`

Note how URL are build when clicking in the form, I guess is using one controller for all this routes, How is it done?.
I Don't think it will be redirecting all the possible routes to a specific controller, (shown below), maybe some sort of dynamic routing?

```
/**
 * @Route("/for_rent/{state}/{beds}_beds/{bath}_bath/{mix_price}-{max_price}_price /{amenities_list}
 * @Route("/for_rent/{state}/{mix_price}-{max_price}_price/{amenities_list}
 * @Route("/for_rent/{state}/{bath}_bath/{mix_price}-{max_price}_price/{amenities_list}
 * @Route("/for_rent/{state}/{mix_price}_price/{amenities_list}
 * @Route("/for_rent/{state}/{beds}_beds/{bath}_bath/{amenities_list}    
 * ........
 */

public function filterAction($state, $beds, $bath, $min_price, $max_price ....)
{
    ....
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For simple queries (i.e. where you don't need to have a data range, such as min-max value), you can use the entity repository to find entities by the request parameters given. Assuming that your entity is `Acme\FooBundle\Entity\Bar`:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
$repo = $em->getRepository('AcmeFooBundle:Bar');

$criteria = array(
    'state' => $state,
    'beds' => $beds,
    // and so on...
);
$data = $repo->findBy($criteria);
```

When building the `$criteria` array, you'll probably want some logic so that you only sort by criteria that have been provided, instead of all possible values. `$data` will then contain all entities that match the criteria.

For more complex queries, you'll want to look into [DQL](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html) (and perhaps a [custom repository](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/working-with-objects.html?highlight=findby#custom-repositories)) for finer-grained control of the entities that you're pulling out.

Answer (score 1):

To construct your routes, i'm sure you had a look at the [Routing](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html) page of the documentation, but did you notice that you can put requirements on routes? [This](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/routing.html) page explains how to do it with annotations.

As for the filtering, I suppose DQL would be ok, but you can also write straight up SQL with Doctrine, and map the results of your query to one or more entities. This is described [here](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/reference/native-sql.html). It may be more flexible than DQL.

Comment: Annotations allow you to match more than one route, which is great, but that does not avoid you to write manually all possible combinations for all filter parameters, I mean, having ABC parameters all possible route combinations will be, ABC, AB, BC, AC, which is a pain. I don't know whether implementing your own routing will allow this kind of dynamic URL matching.

Comment: Found a solution, very  simple                                                                /**
   * @Route("/search/{q}", requirements={"q": ".+"})
   * ........
   */

q will then match everything till the end of the URL. It's then up to you to parse "q", more info http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/slash_in_parameter.html

Answer (score 0):

csg, your solution is good (with @Route("/search/{q})  if you only need to use routing in "one-way". But what if you will need to print some price filter links on page accessible by url: 
http://www.trulia.com/for_sale/30000-1000000_price/10001_zip/

In case of `@Route("/search/{q}` you will not be able to use route method url generate with params.

Answer (score 0):

There is a great Bundle called LexikFormFilterBundle `"lexik/form-filter-bundle": "~2.0"` that helps you generate the complex DQL after the Filter form completed by the user.

I created a Bundle, that depends on it, that changes the types of a given FormType (like the one generated by SencioGeneratorBundle) So you can display the right FilterForm and then create the DQL after it (with Lexik).

You can install it with Composer, following this [README.md](https://github.com/juanmf/FilterTypeGuesserBundle)

All it does is override the Doctrine Type Guesser, that suggests the required FormType for each Entity field, and replace the given Type by the proper LexikFormFilterType. For instance, replaces a simple `NumberType` by a `filter_number` which renders as two numbers, Max and Min interval boundaries.

```
private function createFilterForm($formType)
{
    $adapter = $this->get('dd_form.form_adapter');
    $form = $adapter->adaptForm(
        $formType,
        $this->generateUrl('document_search'),
        array('fieldToRemove1', 'fieldToRemove2')
    );
    return $form;
}
```

Upon form Submit, you just give it to Lexik and run the generated query, as shown in my example.

```
public function searchAction(Request $request)
{
    // $docType = new FormType/FQCN() could do too.
    $docType = 'FormType/FQCN';
    $filterForm = $this->createFilterForm($docType);
    $filterForm->handleRequest($request);

    $filterBuilder = $this->getDocRepo($docType)
        ->createQueryBuilder('e');
    $this->get('lexik_form_filter.query_builder_updater')
        ->addFilterConditions($filterForm, $filterBuilder);

    $entities = $filterBuilder->getQuery()->execute();

    return array(
        'entities'   => $entities,
        'filterForm' => $filterForm->createView(),
    );
}
```